# Attempting to parse out data from excel when the data is in a certain format

Tags: python, regex

I am rather new to regex. I am attempting to pull out all of the monetary and numerical values in these formats ($##,###|$#,###|$####|####|#,####|######) from a certain column in an excel file (df1) . I keep getting the below traceback error

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df1= pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\py_extractnumbers.xlsx', sheet_name = 0)
rows = len(df1)
print(str('Begin loop'))
for i in range(rows):
    NoteValue = df1.loc[i]['Comments']
    compilecheck = re.compile(r'\d\d\d\d'|r'\d,\d\d\d'|r'$\d,\d\d\d'|r'$\d\d,\d\d\d'|r'$\d\d\d\d')
    test= compilecheck.search(str(NoteValue))
    if test != None:
        result = str(test)
        df1['Amount']= df1['Amount'].astype(str)
        df1.at[i,'Amount']=result
        df1.at[i,'Amount']  
        print(str(result))
    else:
        pass
```

Traceback error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: First off, use one regex and use quantifiers: `\$?\d,?\d{3}|\$\d{2},\d{3}` -  `$` is a special character in regex to match end of line - so escape it for the literal dollar sign symbol `$`.

Comment: You can't feed `re.compile()` multiple strings like that. Also, note that `$` is a special character in regex (end of string/line anchor). You'll need to escape it if you want to match a literal dollar sign.

Comment: You'll probably also want to anchor your regex so that you don't match `1,111` if you have a string like `11,111` (according to your rules, it should not match this). Something like `(?<!\d)(?:\$\d{2},\d{3}|\$?\d,?\d{3})\b`. Maybe you would be better off letting us know what the rules are you're trying to match with regex and giving us samples of what to and what not to match?

Comment: Based on your update: `\d{5}|\$\d,?\d{3}|\$\d{2},\d{3}` - but again, you should anchor it.

Comment: I just made the change, this method is far easier than that lengthy method. I am running it now. I appreciate the advice. Will let you know how it does

Comment: Do you really only want to match 4 and 5 digit numbers?

Comment: Yes I am basing it off of a list where the numbers are mixed in with text and I only need the formats that are nested within those strings.

Comment: The change in regex structure and quantifiers worked. Thank you so much!